# jQuery - find text wrapped in brackets?

Tags: jquery, styles, find, replace, addclass

I have nav items, some of them have a label and then a short bit of text after them wrapped in brackets. I need to make this text smaller.

I know how to do a find and replace... but I have no idea how to achieve this. So if the text in my nav item was:

ADF (Australian Defence Personnel)

I'd want to give the brackets + text a new class so that they'd be smaller

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. (Obviously you can change `new_class` to whatever class name you want). [**Here is a link**](http://jsfiddle.net/fpZKG/) where you can check it out in action.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li id="ADF">ADF (Australian Defence Personnel)</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
span.new_class {
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#ADF').html($('#ADF').html().replace(/(\([^)]+\))/, 
                                 '<span class="new_class">$1</span>'));
```

Comment: jsfiddle has panels to put your `css` and `javascript`. Use them rather than including them in the `html` panel. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/fpZKG/1/

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution (also quite naive) is to use

```
$('#text').text().replace('(', '<span class="small">(').replace(')', ')</span>')
```

if your text has the structure

```
<div id="text">ADF (Australian Defence Personnel)</div>
```

and there is always only one piece of text in brackets... this will work but for something more robust, but also more complex you can use regular expressions

```
$('#text').text().replace(/.*?(\(.*?\)).*?/, '<span class="small">$1</span>')
```

jquery will find any of the elements pretty easily. Using

```
$('#someId').text()
```

will give you the text of that element and then the `replace` is regular Javascript and not jquery.